# How to extract fields from a JSON file

Tags: arrays, json, jq

I am new to coding in general but I'm trying to shift my attention to learning JAVA, JSON and JQ.

Having said this, I have created the following JSON file:

```
    {
"users": 
[
    {"Firstname": "Rolo",
        "Lastname": "Car",
          "Hobbies": ["Metalcore", "concerts", "beach"],
        "friends": [
            {"Firstname":"Nitsuki",
                "Lastname": "Saixx"
            },
            {"Firstname":"Confesora",
                "Lastname": "Kahlan"
            }
        ]
    },
    {"Firstname":"Ernest",
        "Lastname": "Vast"
        "Hobbies": ["Barista", "Strategy games", "RPG games"],
        "friends": [
            {"Firstname":"Diana",
                "Lastname": "Vast"
            },
            {"Firstname":"Pat",
                "Lastname": "Vanberg"
            }
        ]
    },
    {"Firstname":"Juls",
        "Lastname": "Santana",
        "Hobbies": ["Sew", "Watch Gossip shows", "Foodie"],
        "friends": [
            {"Firstname":"Laura",
                "Lastname": "Reed"
            },
            {"Firstname":"Sandy",
                "Lastname": "Vast"
            }
        ]
    }
```

I am trying to get the following results:

```
"Rolo"
"Ernest"
"Juls"
```

When I enter the following JQ command

```
cat file.json | jq "[].Firstname"
```

I get the error

```
jq: error (at <stdin>:56): Cannot index array with string "Firstname"
```

Any suggestions on what I could be doing wrong? Thank you so much for your time!

Comment: Please fix the errors in the posted JSON. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couple of issues in the json you posted first:

- You need a comma after `"Lastname": "Vast"`
- You need to complete the object by closing `users` array (add a `]` at the end), and then closing the entire object (adding a `}` at the end)

This command then works:

```bash
cat test.json | jq '.users[].Firstname'
```

You need to tell jq which array you want to get the `Firstname` values from (the `users` array, in your case), as the initial input is <strike>an object, and so cannot be traversed via `[]`</strike> not the collection containing values with a `Firstname` property.

Comment: @anquit - Actually, objects can be traversed via []

Answer (score 0):

.users is an array, so after fixing the obvious errors, you'll find:

```
jq '.users[].Firstname'
```

produces the results you expect.